# Spring+React. How to make calls to the different server?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, maven, webpack

I try to implement Spring+React solution.

I plan to deploy a project on three different servers:

- authorization
- API
- UI

I try to implement the UI server with the Spring+React solution. This [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) describes how to make it. But here is described solution with API and UI in the same server: so, requests from React are executed to the localhost:8080 (of course if we are running a project on this port).

To explain this solution, I will provide the main setup and code:

- pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.XXX.XX</groupId>
    <artifactId>uiserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>UI server</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

...

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::frontend-maven-plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.14.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.13.4</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>webpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The short explanation for the **build** block: the build task consist from:

> - The **install-node-and-npm** command will install node.js and its package
>   management tool, npm, into the target folder. (This ensures the
>   binaries are NOT pulled under source control and can be cleaned out
>   with clean).
> - The **npm** command will execute the npm binary with the provided argument
>   (install). This installs the modules defined in package.json.
> - The **webpack** command will execute webpack binary, which compiles all
>   the JavaScript code based on webpack.config.js

- package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "react_integration",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Demo of ReactJS + Spring Data REST",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@gitlab.com:hhlTer/dd45ui.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rest",
    "hateoas",
    "spring",
    "data",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Valentyn V. Hruzytskyi",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/hhlTer/dd45ui/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/hhlTer/dd45ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9090" < --- there is my trying to set the port for requests (1)
}
```

- client.js:

```
'use strict';

const rest = require('rest');
const defaultRequest = require('rest/interceptor/defaultRequest');
const mime = require('rest/interceptor/mime');
const uriTemplateInterceptor = require('./api/uriTemplateInterceptor');
const errorCode = require('rest/interceptor/errorCode');
const baseRegistry = require('rest/mime/registry');

const registry = baseRegistry.child();

registry.register('text/uri-list', require('./api/uriListConverter'));
registry.register('application/hal+json', require('rest/mime/type/application/hal'));

module.exports = rest
        .wrap(mime, { registry: registry })
        .wrap(uriTemplateInterceptor)
        .wrap(errorCode)
        .wrap(defaultRequest, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/hal+json' }});
```

- app.js, from where calls are executed:

(In the line (2) the path to API is hardcoded)

```js
'use strict';

// tag::vars[]
const React = require('react'); 
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom'); 
const client = require('./client');
// end::vars[]

// tag::app[]
class App extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {persons: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() { 
        client({method: 'GET', path: '/api/person/all'}).done(response => { // < ------------- (2)
            this.setState({persons: response.entity._embedded.persons});
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <PersonList persons={this.state.persons}/>
        )
    }
}
// end::app[]
.....
```

- also there exists **webpack.config.js**, but I don't want to add this code here to avoid excessive information (I am not sure the option has to be set there). If it is necessary - please note me, or see in the [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)

---

So, as was noticed in the package.json in line (2) I determined the path to the API from where I receive the List.

But it is clear to me that the code will not work, since my API is deployed currently on another port (9090) and will be deployed, probably, even on another IP.

I am very new in React and have no idea how to set up port/ip for such requests from .js files. I have tried to set the port in the package.json, line (1), but it doesn't have sense - requests are still passed to the `http://localhost:8880/api/person/all`.

- Question: How to set up IP or port in this case?

Comment: What is the code inside the `client.js` file?  Did you try changing the `path` in your `line (2)` to include the full path like `http://localhost:9090/api/person/all` instead of `/api/person/all`?

Comment: @Vibhor I have added client.js to the answer. According to `line (2)` - I do not want to follow this way, since the server IP and port might be changed and I don't want to update the path in each file in the project.

Comment: Then in that case you will have to use some kind of environment variable strategy where you will define those endpoints in that `.env` files and during deployment of the frontend react code the URLs will be picked from there.

Comment: @Vibhor thanks, this is a solution. But I hoped it will be more flexible - with some property somewhere.